# react parent components without child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, components, state

for example I have 5 components, the first component as the rest of the parent as a child, is all data / response from the API stored in the parent component and then passed to the child component? or each child component has a state to hold data / response from the API?
or vice versa? so each component has its own state

```
export class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dataComponentChild1: [],
      dataComponentChild2: [],
      dataComponentChild3: [],
      dataComponentChild4: [],
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    await Api.post('/example1-endpoint')
    await Api.post('/example2-endpoint')
    await Api.post('/example3-endpoint')
    await Api.post('/example4-endpoint')
    .then((response) => {
      const responseJson = response
      if (responseJson.data.STATUS_CODE === '200') {
        this.setState({
          dataComponentChild1: responseJson.data,
          dataComponentChild2: responseJson.data,
          dataComponentChild3: responseJson.data,
          dataComponentChild4: responseJson.data,
        });
      }
    })
  }

  render() {

    const {dataComponentChild1,dataComponentChild2,dataComponentChild3,dataComponentChild4} = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Component1 props1 = {dataComponentChild1} />
        <Component2 props2 = {dataComponentChild2} />
        <Component3 props3 = {dataComponentChild3} />
        <Component4 props4 = {dataComponentChild4}/>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```

and what if I want to post / get to many endpoints at the same time?
Is my method above correct?

Comment: If the response of each API is used only within a single child component, it is better to invoke the relevant API call from the  `componentDidMount` method of each child component and store the result in the child component's state itself.

Comment: Also, you cannot use `then-catch` with `async-await` invocations. Please read on the difference between `promise` based asynchronous syntax and `async-wait` syntax. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/async-await-vs-promises-4fe98d11038f

Comment: If your components state is exclusive, you could choose to save the state of each component in its own state, moreover you could write only a single Component and pass down only the changed data (e.g. endpoint) and call that endpoint in the common components 'componentDidMount'. Lot of duplicate code can be removed by this approach.